# What is it called when anime is drawn with nonblack borders?

Tags: anime-production

In [No Game No life](https://myanimelist.net/anime/19815/No_Game_No_Life), the borders of the characters and man objects are red lines.  In [Netoge no Yome wa Onnanoko ja Nai to Omotta](https://myanimelist.net/anime/31404/Netoge_no_Yome_wa_Onnanoko_ja_Nai_to_Omotta), the borders of the characters and objects in the game world are blue.  Almost all other anime have black lines around the characters and objects.

What is this phenomenon called?

### No Game No Life:

[image]

### Netoge no Yome wa Onnanoko ja Nai to Omotta

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that it's just a stylistic choice and there's no specific name for it, but I'd be interested to know if there's actually an answer to this.

Comment: I was hoping for it being a named stylistic choice so I could look for more of it.  I think it's kind of cool.

Comment: I remember for Nagi no Asukara (A Lull in the Sea), they decided to have the sea kids/people drawn with blue outlines due to... being sea people. I believe I read it out of the art book included with the premium Blu-ray box (I'll have to double-check), but the art book just said "drawn with a blue outline" or something to that effect, although obviously that's how it was translated into English. I would be interested if there was a particular name for this, but a big part of me thinks there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

According to the book 『アニメーションの基礎知識大百科』(*Encyclopedia of animation basics*) by Kamimura Sachiko, the Japanese term for this is 「色トレス」（*iro toresu*, meaning "colored trace", see p.99）. In some cases of *iro toresu* the borderline (trace) is given the same hue as the area it surrounds, making the borderline essentially invisible, and this is referred to as 「T.P同色」（T = trace, P = paint, and 同色 means "same color", see p.84）. The examples you gave fall under the opposite term 「T.P別色」, meaning that the trace and the paint have different colors.